# Server Side Validation using Spring Web MVC validator class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing app using Spring Web MVC, Hibernate..

Now, i have my login page configuration like :

```
<bean name="/uservalidate.htm" class="UserValidateFormController">
        <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
        <property name="commandName" value="User"/>
        <property name="commandClass" value="User"/>
        <property name="formView" value="login"/>
        <property name="userSecurityProcessor" ref="IUserSecurityProcessor"/>
         <property name="validator">
            <bean class="LoginValidator"/>
        </property>
        <property name="successView" value="layout.jsp"/>
```

Now, after submitting from login page control goes to Validator Class i.e. LoginValidator..

But, at that class i am not getting reference of my userSecurityProcessor which gives me server side data..

Can anybody please suggest, how can i check Username and Password in my Validator class..?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of LoginValidator as a separate bean. In your LoginValidator, add a userSecurityProcessor property. Then in your config file inject a reference to an instance of a IUserSecurityProcessor just as you do above. So something like this:

```
<bean name="loginValidator" class="LoginValidator">
<property name="userSecurityProcessor" ref="IUserSecurityProcessor"/>
</bean>
```

Then change

```
<bean name="/uservalidate.htm" class="UserValidateFormController">
    <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="User"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="User"/>
    <property name="formView" value="login"/>
    <property name="userSecurityProcessor" ref="IUserSecurityProcessor"/>
     <property name="validator">
        <bean class="LoginValidator"/>
    </property>
    <property name="successView" value="layout.jsp"/>
```

to

```
<bean name="/uservalidate.htm" class="UserValidateFormController">
    <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="User"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="User"/>
    <property name="formView" value="login"/>
    <property name="userSecurityProcessor" ref="IUserSecurityProcessor"/>
     <property name="validator" ref = "loginValidator"/>
    <property name="successView" value="layout.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can' get `userSecurityProcessor` in Validator. The only object you will get is, the `commandObject`. In your case it is `User`

But in case you need that, then you will have to bind it in Validator

```
<bean id="myValidator" class="LoginValidator">
    <property name="userSecurityProcessor" ref="IUserSecurityProcessor"/>
</bean>
```

Now, bind this validator with your Form.

Answer (score -1):

public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
     User user = (User) target;
     String username = user.getUsername();
     String password = user.getPassword();
     ..........
    }

Comment: The question implies that UserSecurityProcessor is needed to validate username and password (which seems like a good approach to me).

Comment: Maniganda Prakash : That's not i have mentioned in my question.. I have clearly specify that how can i get ref of userSecurityProcessor bean in my Validator class.... 

Both the ans of bpapa and of Rakesh Juyal are perfect..